# How to hide a pre-built app tab from a fanpage temporarily during development

Tags: facebook, tabs, fan-page

I'm wondering how to hide a Facebook tab from a published fanpage while the tab is under development, so that it only appears for page Admins?

I know you can do this for custom built apps (the sandbox setting), but here I'm not referring to a custom built app, but prebuilt apps like Static HTML.

In order to edit tabs it seems that they have to be added to the page, in order to be able to edit them. That's a problem when customizing a Facebook tab, as you don't want your fans to see your work-in-progress content until it's ready to be published.

Any one who has experience with this?

Comment: Set up a second test page only visible to its admins, embed the app there, configure it how you like – and then transfer those settings to the app embedded on your live site.

Comment: Hi CBroe,

Thanks for the answer. Yeah, that a way to go about it. But you would have to manually transfer and setup everything twice, which would be a pain and could very easily introduce mistakes if you forget something. Also having two versions would force you to do any updates twice. If there's no "hidden page" functionality in Facebook maybe this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could show it only when an admin is logged in by checking the session.

I can't help you more because there is too few information of what you're using..

Comment: Hi Dediqated,

Thanks for the answer - sounds like a great solution! How exactly do you "check the session so that it only shows when the admin is logged in"? 
I don't see that option anywhere in settings?

I'd be happy to provide more info - What more would you need?

Anders